# How to convert a SET back to a HASHMAP for display in customAdapter

Tags: android

I am really stuck with this problem and would appreciate some help.

Firstly, I have a service running which contains a simple hashmap

ORIG_MSG_MAP is a hashmap with Integer,String key value pairs. The service has a method to return the contents of the hashmap as a set

```
//get entries in the hash 
public Set<Entry<String, Integer>> getNumbers() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    return ORIG_MSG_MAP.entrySet();


}
```

in my activity I am interacting with the service and then I call my constructor in customAdapter which needs to work with a hashmap not a SET

ACTIVITY

```
      /** Defines callbacks for service binding, passed to bindService() */
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
@Override
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
// We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance
LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
mService = binder.getService();
mBound = true;
Set<Entry<String, Integer>> whatsup = mService.getNumbers();
```

----> The question marks should be a reference to a hash with key,value pairs <---- 
    setListAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(DynamicLists.this, R.layout.row, ???));

Constuctor for MyCustomAdapter he expects a hash

```
public MyCustomAdapter(DynamicLists dynamicLists, int row, HashMap<String, Integer> map){ 
mData = map;
mKeys = mData.keySet().toArray(new String[map.size()]);
Log.d(TAG, "INSIDE ADAPTER constructor HELLO WORLD " + map.entrySet());
```

}

Can you please help me convert a set back to a hash

Thanks,

Graham

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give that a try :

```
Set<Entry<String, Integer>> yourSet;
HashMap<String,Integer> yourMap = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
for (Entry<String,Integer> entry : yourSet) {
    yourMap.put(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue());
}
```

In fact, simply add each entry of your set into a new HashMap